# How can I check if a given image is CMYK in php?

Tags: php

How can I check if a given image is CMYK in php?

Do you know any solution without Imagick?

thanks.

Comment: One indication that an image file *might* be a CMYK file is if GD bombs out with an error when you try to open it. :) Other than that, there doesn't seem to be any ready-made method - [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) doesn't seem to provide the information. (although it can't be that difficult to get this out of the file's header bytes.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use the [getimagesize($filename)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function in PHP to achieve this.

```
<?php
    $blah = getimagesize($filename);
    if($blah['channels']==4){
        // it is cmyk
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ah, nice! Didn't know/remember getimagesize did that.

Comment: It does but not for PNG

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in jpg format, you can check SOF (Start Of Frame - SOF0 or SOF2) section in jpeg header (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)).

```
function isCMYK($img_data) {
    // Search for SOF (Start Of Frame - SOF0 or SOF2) section in header
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG
    if (($sof = strpos($img_data, "\xFF\xC0")) === false) {
        // FF C2 is progressive encoding while FF C0 is standard encoding
        $sof = strpos($img_data, "\xFF\xC2");
    } 
    return $sof? ($img_data[($sof + 9)] == "\x04") : false;
}

$img_data variable is the raw file contents (e.g. $img_data = file_get_contents($filename))
```